# Issue with static hosting on s3 and cloudfront [OAI]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, devops, amazon-cloudfront

I created an `s3` bucket, with static hosting enabled.
I created a cloudfront distribution with an access identity `FOO`.

My goal is to have a cloudfront distribution that can access s3 (including paths) in order to serve a static website.

The policy on my bucket is:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "...",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity FOO"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I changed the origin name on the cloufront distribution to point to my s3 hosting address:

```
my-bucket.s3-website-my-region-1.amazonaws.com
```

If I now visit the cloudfront address, I get `Access Denied 403`.

If I change the permissions of the `index.html` file on s3 in order to grant read and list permissions to everyone, then it all works.

But, this feels like a hack, not to mention that I have to post-modify permissions after deploying and all.

Is it possible to have static hosting on s3 that is only served through cloudfront with OAI?

Comment: Disable static website hosting when using OAI. Try again after disabling - does it work as expected?

Comment: Detailed Information with different scenarios https://serverfault.com/questions/581268/amazon-cloudfront-with-s3-access-denied

Answer (score 0):

When using Amazon CloudFront to provide access to an Amazon S3 bucket using OAI, simply select the bucket in CloudFront rather than pointing to the website URL.

The documentation says: "For Origin domain, select the bucket that you created."

See: [Use CloudFront to serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/)

If you want the root URL to default an `index.html` file, then you will need to configure this behaviour on the CloudFront Distribution rather than relying on S3 doing it for you.

See: [Specifying a Default Root Object - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html)

Comment: I followed the docs, my issue is that for some reason the files pushed to s3 (via a github action) do not have the right permissions. It might be related to the organisation settings, it might be some owner issue, or the actions, or something else... I am wondering if there is a minimal example that works, including resolved paths

Comment: Did you change CloudFront to reference the **bucket** directly, rather than the Website Hosting URL? You can also **turn off website hosting** since it isn't used for the CloudFront connection.

Answer (score 0):

Along with s3:GetObject use listbucket permission as well then it works as expected

```
{
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity FOO"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity FOO"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```